# gcc: fatal error: no input files compilation terminated

Tags: compiling, gcc

I'm new to linux environment. I created a file s1.c in a folder named 'program' which is present in desktop. When I try to compile my code using "/program gcc s1.c " it's  showing  "gcc: error: s1.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated."
What may be the problem

Comment: Change to "folder" `program`; make sure the file `s1.c` is in the current directory by running `ls`; then compile the program with `gcc s1.c`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are not in the same directory or you are not firing the command for `program` folder where `s1.c` file is located.

Make sure that you are running `gcc s1.c` while you are in `program` directory or you can try `gcc program/s1.c` if you are not in `program` directory.

You can refer this attached image for more info.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cd ~/Desktop/program
$ gcc s1.c -o s1
$ ./s1
```

- The first command changes in to the directory `~/Desktop/program`.
- The second compiles your C program `s1.c1`, the resulting executable is called `s1`.
- The third command executes the executable called `s1`.

Comment: A little bit of context and detail will go a long way to explain why this so,union might work 

Comment: I don't understand what you're suggesting. Context? An explanation of what these commands do?